# Low cost quad-core mini pc options

Tags: processor, mini-pc, thin-mini-itx

I am a post-doc researcher working on computational modelling projects.

In my spare time, I like to code open-source projects on some topics outside of my university role. I intend to set up a low-cost home workstation for this purpose which shall also double up as a small NFS server for the family.

Unfortunately, due to family commitments and medical bills, I can't afford a high end machine.

Are there any NUC or other mini PCs out there that have 4 physical cores for below £250 ($300) in the UK? Considering that adding RAM in a mini pc is quite difficult, I am thinking about 8GB DDR4 RAM. It will probably run CentOS or Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the specification below to build a PC

**Processor:**  `AMD Ryzen 5 3400G ( CPU Cores: 4; Threads: 8; GPU Cores: 11; Base Clock: 3.7GHz; Max Boost Clock: 4.2 GHz; Memory Channels: 2)` **$145**

**Motherboard:**  `Gigabyte B450M-S2H (CPU: AMD Ryzen; Chipset: AMD B450; Memory: 2 x DDR4, Max. 32 GB; 3 x PCI Express slots)` **$70**

**RAM:** `G.Skill RIPJAWS-V 8GB 2666bus Desktop RAM` **$40**

**HDD:** `SEAGATE BARRACUDA 1TB 7200 RPM SATA DESKTOP HDD` **$43**

**CASE:** `Any decent casing with Power Supply` **$30**

***Total price of the build is around $325, You can adjust the price downgrading the processor if you can't go beyond $300***

**NB: You can buy a SSD later when you have money for boot drive, which will boost the performance of your PC**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an older model barebones XPC. Comes with PSU and CPU fan/heatsink with MB in small but surprisingly capable case. You choose and install processor, memory, graphics card and storage.